# Create Jobs and schedule them on Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to bigquery and need to do some tests on it. Looking through bigquery documentation, i can't find nothing about creating jobs and scheduling them.

I found in other page on internet that the only available method is creating a bucket in google cloud storage and create a function in cloud functions using javascript, and inside it's body  write down the sql query.
Can someone help me here? Is it true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing as you mix scheduling jobs with defining a query in a cloud function.

There is a difference in scheduling jobs vs scheduling queries.

1. BigQuery offers Scheduled queries. See [docs here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries).
2. BigQuery Data Transfer Service (schedule recurring data loads from GCS.) See [docs here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-storage-transfer).
3. If you want to schedule jobs for (load, delete, copy jobs etc) you better do this with a trigger on the observed resource like Cloud Storage new file, a Pub/Sub message, a HTTP trigger all this wired in a Cloud Function.

Some other related blog posts:

- [How to schedule a BigQuery ETL job with Dataprep](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-schedule-a-bigquery-etl-job-with-dataprep-b1c314883ab9)
- [Scheduling BigQuery Jobs: This time using Cloud Storage & Cloud Functions](https://shinesolutions.com/2018/01/21/scheduling-bigquery-jobs-this-time-using-cloud-storage-cloud-functions/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Pentium10. In fact i really don't uderstand the difference between the "scheduled queries" and "schedule jobs", but thanks for the guidance. I'll try the sugestions and see how they work. Thanks a lot!